# Minimum value of $\frac{a^2 + b^2 +1 }{a(b+1)}$

Tags: inequality, optimization, rational-functions

Find the minimum value of $\dfrac{a^2 + b^2 +1  }{a(b+1)}$  for $a$, $b$ positive reals.

I know that the solution is $\sqrt{2}$ using perfect squares, derivatives, etc. However, I want to find the minimum using inequalities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe, $$b^2+1\ge \frac{(b+1)^2}{2}$$
Using the A.M-G.M inequality,
$$a^2+\frac{(b+1)^2}{2}\ge \sqrt{2}\cdot a(b+1)$$
Equality happens at $b=1, a=\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Best way! ,thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, substituting $b=1$ gives an upper bound on the value.
$$\inf \left\{ \frac{a^2+b^2+1}{a(b+1)} : a>0,b>0\right\} \leq  \inf \left\{ \frac{a^2+2}{2a} : a>0\right\} $$
Second, using the AM-GM inequality

$$\frac{a^2+2}{2a}=\frac{a+2/a}{2} \geq \sqrt{a \cdot 2/a}=\sqrt{2}. $$
Combined this gives an upper bound on the minimum of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I cannot understand first line, How to find b=1 for gives equation to squeeze between \sqrt{2}

Comment: While correct, this is not a good solution as you just happened to chance upon the equality case of $b=1$. Can you justify why we choose that value?

Comment: @CalvinLin I saw the similarity with Newton-Raphson's method for finding the square root of 2.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, this is a solution after one knows (or guesses) the minimizer. "What is a good solution" is an interesting question. Sometimes the thinking process is complicated, but the solution is simple. For example, we use calculus to motivate the solution, but the solution does not include calculus at all. Sometimes, once we know or guess the optimal value, the problem becomes simple. For inequalities, we often can guess the optimal value. For example, for symmetric 3-var inequalities, often the optimal value occurs when two of the three variables are equal.

Comment: @CalvinLin By the way, user1337's solution gives $\inf_{a, b>0} f(a,b) = \inf_{a>0} \inf_{b>0} f(a,b) \le \inf_{a>0} f(a, 1) = \sqrt 2$. How to obtain $\inf_{a, b>0} f(a,b) = \sqrt 2$?